# How to create a Folder in Yahoo Mail using YQL?

Tags: php, api, yahoo, yql

I'm trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO ymail.folders(folder.folderInfo.name) VALUES('Lykebox')
```

But i'm receiving this error:

> No matching endpoints for verb 'insert' in table 'ymail.folders'.

If it's not possible, please let me know about any ways to create a folder with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try the [api](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/CreateFolder.html#CreateFolderExamples) to create a folder
**CreateFolder** adds a new personal folder to the user’s MyFolder list. Folder names can be letters, numbers, and the hyphen (-), space ( ), and underline (_) characters only.

preference is given to the json endpoint [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/JSON-RPCEndpoint.html#JSON-RPCSampleRequest) imho :)